# program crash with boost::asio::spawn and socket::async_receive_from

Tags: c++, boost-asio

```
int main() {
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  Worker ob1(&io_service);

  ob1.AsyncRead();
  io_service.run();

}

void Worker::AsyncRead() {
   socket.async_receive_from(buffer,endpoint, handler);
}

void handler (const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_received) {
   if(!error)
       handleData();
   AsyncRead();
}
```

Now this works perfectly fine. But if I use boost::Spawn() to do asyncRead() it crashes.

```
  void work(boost::asio::io_service* io_service) {

     auto ob1 = std::make_shared<Worker>(io_service);
  boost::asio::spawn(*io_service, [ob1](
                                      boost::asio::yield_context yield) {

      ob1->AsyncRead();

   });

  }

   int main() {
      boost::asio::io_service io_service;
       work(&io_service);

      io_service.run();

    }
```

The stack trace for the crash is:

```
PC: @           0x4e3502 boost::asio::basic_io_object<>::get_service()
*** SIGSEGV (@0x18) received by PID 25135 (TID 0x7f6bde13b7c0) from PID 24; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f6bdd37d390 (unknown)
    @           0x4e3502 boost::asio::basic_io_object<>::get_service()
    @           0x4e3074 boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket<>::async_receive_from<>()
```

I want to make it work with `boost::spawn()`. What will happen to `spawn()` once my `work()` returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, your code cannot possibly compile (`handler` must be a non-static member function of `Worker`, but that means it doesn't satisfy the handler requirements for `async_receive_from`.

But the problem you ask about appears simpler:

```
 auto ob1 = std::make_shared<Worker>(io_service);
```

Creates a shared pointer

```
 boost::asio::spawn(*io_service, [ob1](
                                  boost::asio::yield_context yield) {
```

Posts a coro onto the service, that holds a copy of `ob1` so it stays alive. So far so good.

```
  ob1->AsyncRead();
```

This does an `async_recieve_from`, which naturally returns immediately, the coro is done and `ob1` is released. But `async_receive_from` is still pending on the  service.

If you want to use async operations inside a coro, you have to pass the yield_context as a completion token. You didn't do that.

Your code should conceptually look like:

```
  void work(boost::asio::io_service* io) {

  boost::asio::spawn(*io_service, [io](boost::asio::yield_context yield) {

       udp::socket socket(*io); 
       // ... more

       udp::endpoint ep;
       char buffer[1024];
       socket.async_receive_from(buffer, ep, yield); // throws on error

   });
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation.  but `async_receive_from()` does not accept `yeild_context` as a parameter. Do we convert it to handler?

Comment: so even if i pass `completion token`, `ob1` would be still out of scope and it won't work right? or it will block coro and make `AsyncRead()` to block?

Comment: Do you know what a co-op to routine is? Have you even _tried_ passing `yield_context` as the handler before claiming it can't be done? I think you have some reading to do. Any boost example for `spawn` would show you this, and also explain your confusion about 'blocking' (it's called suspend and resume in coroutines).

Comment: Ironically, if not for that, there would really never be a reason to use `spawn` at all. So I wonder how you got to the point of asking these questions, without reading the documentation. Or did you mean to ask what the documentation means? Because in that case next time better quote the code from those docs and state what about it you don't quite understand.

Comment: Hmm "co-op to routine" was my phone's correction for coroutine. Sorry

Comment: yes. I dont know anything about it. if you provide me any link to code that will be really helpful. thanks

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/spawn/echo_server.cpp